Smoothness of Manifolds Vs Curves/Images given by Vector Valued Functions
Background:
Smooth Manifolds
Let $X$ be a topological manifold and $\mathfrak{A}$ be an atlas on $X$. We call $M=\{X, \mathfrak{A}\}$ a smooth manifold if $\mathfrak{A}$ is a maximal smooth ($C^\infty$) atlas.
Smooth Curves/Images (Vector Valued Functions)
Let $r:I\to \mathbb R^n$ be a vector valued function  with $r(t, ...)=⟨f(t,...), ...⟩$. We call the curve $r(I\subseteq \mathbb R)$ smooth if and only if it has a $C^1$ parametrization $p$ with $p'(t)\neq0$ for all $(t)\in I$. Extended to higher dimensions we have that the image $r(I\subseteq \mathbb R^m)$, with $r:I\to \mathbb R^n$, is smooth if and only if the image has a $C^1$ parametrization $p$ and the Jacobian Matrix of $p$ has full rank at every point of $I$.
Question:
Are these two definitions of smoothness equivalent? I.e. if $r$ is a vector valued function, is its curve/image being smooth equivalent to its curve/image being a smooth manifold (admitting a smooth structure). If so, how do you prove this, and if not, then why? Are these just two different concepts with the same name? I understand that "parametric" and normal smoothness are different, but how do these relate to admitting a smooth structure, or do they even relate?
Corrected Hypothesis:
Let $r:I\subseteq \mathbb R^m\to \mathbb R^n$ be a proper injective immersion,then $r(I)$ being smooth is equivalent to $r(I)$ being a smooth manifold.
$\Rightarrow$ Let $r:I\subseteq \mathbb R^m\to \mathbb R^n$ be a proper injective immersion, then $rank(J_r(t))=min\{m,n\},\ \forall t\in I \Leftrightarrow$ $r(I)$ admitting a smooth structure.
$\Rightarrow$ $r:I\subseteq \mathbb R^m\to \mathbb R^n$ is a proper injective immersion $\Leftrightarrow$ $r(I)$ admitting a smooth structure.
$\Rightarrow$ $r:I\subseteq \mathbb R^m\to \mathbb R^n$ is a proper injective immersion $\Rightarrow$ $r(I)$ is a smooth manifold.
And so it is true?
And if $r$ is not a proper injective immersion, then $r(I)$ is not a manifold? (So it is a necessary condition)
My Findings
(Take these with a grain of salt, as there might be incorrect statements)
Firstly an example (This is partially what motivated me to ask this question):
Given the function $x^2=y^3$, we can write it as a function $r(t)=⟨t^2, t^3⟩$. Then $r$ is $C^\infty$, however since $r'(0)=0$, it is not a smooth curve. Now, let's consider the curve as a manifold. $r(I)$ is a topological manifold, and so we will try to show that it does not admit a maximal smooth atlas. We will consider the neighbourhood of $r(0)$. Now there are multiple methods I tried to use.

Consider the charts $(U^-, \phi^-)$ and $(U^+, \phi^+)$ ($U^-$ as in the neighbourhood given by $r(I^-)$ with $I^-\subseteq \mathbb R\setminus \mathbb R^+$, $U^+$ similarly). We have that $\phi^{-1}=r$ for both + and - and then $\phi^-(x, y)=(-\sqrt x, \sqrt[3] y)$ and $\phi^+(x, y)=(\sqrt x, \sqrt[3] y)$.Next take $r((-\epsilon, \epsilon))$. Then there must exist a homeomorphism $\phi:r((-\epsilon,\epsilon))\to\mathbb R^1$, such that it is smoothly compatible with the other charts. I get stuck here proving or disproving this.
It does not have a tangent space at $r(0)$. I am not sure about this, since what if you take $T_0r(I)=\{0\}$ to be the tangent space.
Considering a diffeomorphism from the open neighbourhood of $r(0)$ to $\mathbb R$. This is more like looking at embeddings. So I am not sure if this even makes sense. One idea might be to show that $r(I)$ being a smooth curve is equivalent to it being a smooth submanifold of $\mathbb R^n$.

All of this made me question the similarity of the two definitions so I tried proving the equivalence.
Firstly if you take a $C^1\ r$, with $r'(t,...)\neq 0$ then that means you can construct a tangent space at each point, implying that it is possible to give $r(I)$ a smooth structure? The other side of the equivalence I am not so sure about.
I do have many more ideas, but before thinking about them I would like to see if it even makes sense.

This algebraic curve actually has a name: the semicubic parabola, and it has a cusp singularity at the origin. In other words, we have to exclude the origin in order to consider it a smooth $1$-manifold.

The condition that a set admits a smooth structure is very weak (only depends on the cardinality) unless you require the smooth structure to be compatible with some other given structure on the set.

Also note that we can have "bad parametrizations" of nice curves with unnecessary zeroes of the derivative, e.g. $t\mapsto(t^3,t^3)$ on $(-1,1)$.

Another note: if by "$(t,\dots)$" you mean to allow higher-dimensional manifolds, then the $r'\ne0$ condition should probably actually be something about the Jacobian having full rank.

See immersion.

@Karl That's a mistake on my part with the bad parametrizations. The definition should be that the curve is smooth iff there exists a parametrization of the curve satisfying the given properties.

@Karl Yeah, I did mean higher dimensions, It should be that the Jacobian has full rank as you said. I will add this.

I think looking at the definition of an immersion, and the difference between an immersion and an embedding, is likely to answer your questions.

You’re missing an important hypothesis. You need $r$ to be a one-to-one immersion in order to get the image to be (even locally) a submanifold. And then you need properness for a global embedding.

The answer to your question as it is posed now is a no. But with some extra conditions it is true. Given the non-smooth curve in your example, you can flatten it out to an $\mathbb{R}$ topologically and then give it the usual structure. So what you need is to prescribe how the smooth structure of your curve should interact with that of the ambient space. To do this, look up what an immersion is, as suggested by Karl.

Another problem is a global one. You can imagine a parametrized curve looping back on it self to make a hook-like shape that wouldn't even be a manifold. to fix this look up what an embedding is.

For now, I'll add the additional conditions, and think about it some more.

As I see it the hypothesis is then true by definition with the additional conditions, and that smoothness of the image of a function is the stronger concept of the two, i.e. if the image of a function is a topological manifold and the image is smooth, then the image admits a smooth structure, however there are examples of images of functions which are smooth but are not manifolds. Of course this is all only considering sets created as images of maps $I \subseteq\mathbb R^m\to \mathbb R^n$.
